# Actionscript 3 and php data exchange, was downloading whole script instead of running it

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

Im using FlashDevelop with flixel library(Don't know if it matters).

I've been looking around for days (including in this page), and I'm really tired of finding half answers which wont work when I try them.

This is the simple php script:

```
<?php
    print("name=".$_POST['name']);
?>
```

Right now I have this code in AS3 that sends a value inside a variable **name** to "test.php" when I click anywhere on the flash window:

```
package{
    import org.flixel.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class TestState extends FlxState{
        override public function create():void {
            FlxG.mouse.show();
            FlxG.bgColor = 0x00000000;
            FlxG.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
        }

        private function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void{
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.php");
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            vars.name = "Joshua";
            request.data = vars;

            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completed);
            loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
            loader.load(request);
        }

        private function completed(event:Event): void {
            //trace(what should I put here to get the reply?)
        }
    }   
}
```

What should I put inside the trace's parenthesis to get the server reply?

Comment: The error was in `var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.php");` 
It should have been `var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/test.php");` 
(In my case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data from a `URLLoader` is stored in the URLLoader's `data` property. Generally, most people access it in the `Event.COMPLETE` handler through `event.target.data` (you are guaranteed to not have any scope issues using that), although you can of course access it through the original URLLoader variable (you call it `loader`) as well

This is a fairly common task in Flash, though. You should have been able to find this on any number of sites and in the AS3 liveDocs (see [`URLLoader.data`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#data)) quite easily (this is likely why you received a downvote).

Comment: When i wrote trace(event.target.data) this is the output I got: %3C%3Fphp%0D%0A%09print%28%27name=%27%2E%24%5FPOST%5B%27name%27%5D%29%3B%0D%0A%3‌​F%3E Which is probably the whole php document, it doesn't even turn the $_POST['name'] into the value I sent.

Comment: That's because your PHP return is incorrect. It's returning the actual PHP file rather than running the script.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really need to fix this, but I don't understand what you mean with PHP return, is it a server configuration error or an error in the code?

Comment: Are you actually running a server? Judging by the URL in your request, it would have to be local, so are you running XAMMP or similar? You are downloading the PHP file rather than running it, so it must be a server issue.

Comment: Yeah I'm using WAMP, thanks for your help, I'll probably give up since I'm terrible in that kind of configurations.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WAMP (only MAMP and XAMMP) but try throwing the PHP file into the `htdocs` folder of the install. Then start Apache and access it via `http://localhost/test.php`. Your virtual host does not encompass your entire machine, only select folders. htdocs is the easiest to use since it should work without any vhost/hosts configuration. This is likely why you are downloading the file rather than running it.

Comment: I just had to add the http://localhost part, thanks a lot for your help. These are the kind of mistakes people make because not all details are explained completely in other pages. Now hopefully if somebody else does something similar they will find the answer here.